How to solve second order PDE with non-constant coefficients?
$$t \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t}+2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x^2$$
How to solve this linear non-constant coefficients non-homogeneous second order PDE?
I am new to this, so I would really appreciate so much if anyone directs me in the right direction.

By setting $v = u_{x}$. You should also show your current working, else this question is likely to be closed.

Hint to start: First solve the homogeneous equation $$ t \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t} + 2 \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$$
You might note that this says
$$ t \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} + 2 v = 0 $$
where $v = \partial u/\partial t$.
This is easy to solve if you think of it as an ordinary differential equation with $t$ as a parameter.

Would you please recommend a book or a link from which I can learn in depth about these pde's
